# Creating HTML form from mysql table like gii of yii framework

Tags: php, mysql, forms, yii, gii

Is there any application which automatically creates html form from given mysql table like the one `gii` does of `yii framework`.

Or, is there any way, i can use `gii` for my own purpose without using using `yii framework`.

I don't want complete `CRUD` feature in it, Even if it's just list out my data with pagination, that will do my work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URL will help you!

http://developer.ifreelance.asia

I found this on facebook page. I use it myself, and this is real handy.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly, what i am looking for. IF there would be little indentaion and new line, it will be easy to read. But Great application. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you really think about it, phpmyadmin creates forms using the database structure. The ultimate CMS is phpmyadmin :).

Anyway to answer your question. You can always create your own Gii template that creates it as you need it. I have custom models and custom forms that get created. There is nothing that prevents me from rolling out anything I actually want with Gii.

The only 1 problem that I can think about is that you create the model and then, based on the Yii model you create the CRUD. If you really want to use Gii you should create your own model however you want, create a Yii model too (quite easy to create both, one after the other as you can use 2 different templates) then create the CRUD based on the Yii model, but the CRUD you need.

Probably you can do it directly but I have never tried it.

Point is, you can use Gii to create a model for any ORM. It just creates a text file and you can modify it. The CRUD might require 2 steps but you should also be able to create the CRUN as you want.

Comment: I don't want it to fulfill CRUD feature, but just listing of data in table format with pagination is more than enough for me.

Comment: You can just create the admin or index file. Or do you actually want to use CGridView without Yii?

Comment: I am not Yii developer, so i don't know much about `CGridView`. I just want some app which will automatically fetch my listed data from mysql and show them in table with pagination like phpmyadmin does. Just display table with pagination and nothing much.

Comment: So use Yii. It is very simple, create the Model, create just the admin table (no need to create the other CRUD) and enjoy it.

Comment: How to create `Model` ? Do you mean database ? if yes, i already have it. I am not familiar with `Yii Framework`, Nor i am unable to understand their documentation. :(

Comment: In Gii you have the option to create a model. Create it. Afterwards you can create the CRUD. You just need to create the admin.php file and the _search.php file.